# html web component html content?

Tags: javascript, html

Providing innerHTML as a string is seems very error prone while document.createElement is very tedious. Is there a JSX-like way to define web component's html content?

Instead of doing innerHTML string

```
class Foo extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `<p>foo</p>`;
  }
}
```

Do something like

```
class Foo extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = (<p>foo</p>);
  }
}
```

Comment: If there was, we wouldn't need JSX...

Comment: Yes, there is, however not sure if it less tedious then create a function which create and append elements.
check out this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements

Comment: Check out [`lit-html`](https://lit.dev/docs/libraries/standalone-templates/).